# Rails unobtrusive ajax:failure event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have added success and failure handlers to a `:remote => true` link generated by rails:

HAML:

```
link_to 'Cancel', cancel_path(block), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :id => "cancel-button"
```

JS:

```
 $('#cancel-button').live('ajax:failure', function(){console.log('failure');});
 $('#cancel-button').live('ajax:success', function(){console.log('success');});
```

When the response from the server is `200` the console output works - success.

When the response from the server is `404`, neither of these handlers fire. No output.

The same is true when the server returns a `500` status - no output.

Any ideas why rails.js might not be catching this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops. Contrary to [the blog post I was reading](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) the name of the event is actually `ajax:error` rather than `ajax:failure`...